# Can a Quorum network be cloned?

Tags: quorum, backup, clone

I wanted to know if a Private Protected Network be cloned/replicated to have a backup of the network, which would be helpful in times of network failure.

Also is there a possibility of backup of data from one network to another.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you really mean ***network*** failure or **node** failure. If you ensure each node is able to recover from data failure, then that should cover all disaster scenarios.

The following document describes how to backup/restore quorum data in case of node failure: https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/latest/HowTo/Use/import-export/

Tessera has the ability to recover data from the other nodes, described under here: https://docs.tessera.consensys.net/en/latest/HowTo/Configure/Transaction-manager/#how-it-works

You can also run quorum using high availability mode, which is described here: https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/latest/HowTo/Configure/HighAvailability/